# Get print jobs that are older than 1 hour using powershell

Tags: powershell, printing

I want to search for all print jobs which are older than 1 hour still in queue along with only printers where status is error/Paused.

I tried the below code but not getting the correct TIme Difference, also node name is not showing in the result. Can anyone please help?

Query:

```
$old = get-date -Format 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss tt'

$PrinterStatus=Get-Printer -ComputerName "Hgjyu-79ujk"  | Get-Printjob | select 
   @{name="Name";expression={$_.printerName}} , @{name="Submitted Time";
   expression={$_.SubmittedTime}} , jobstatus, NodeName  , @{name="Document Name";
   expression={$_.documentname}} ,@{n='TIme Difference';
   e={[math]::Truncate(($_.old - $_.SubmittedTime).TotalHours)}} |

Where-Object {$_.jobstatus -ne "Normal" -or $_.SubmittedTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) } |

Sort-Object -Property jobstatus -Descending
```

Result:

```
Submitted Time : 12/4/2020 7:36:30 PM
JobStatus      : Error
NodeName       : 
Document Name  : NewDoc
Difference     : -17697523
```

Comment: The selector is wrong most of the time. for exemple $.printerName --> $_.printerName.

Comment: Your `Get-Printer` function is pretty long. Did you go through it step by step to know exactly what the content is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use code blocks for code when posting a question.

`-Format` in `Get-Date` returns a string so you can't compare `$old` with `$_.SubmittedTime`

`Get-PrintJob` returns a [MSFT_PrintJob](https://wutils.com/wmi/root/standardcimv2/msft_printjob/) so it does not contain the `NodeName` value. It does however have a `PrinterName` property.

Example

```bsh
$CurrentTime = Get-Date

Get-Printer -ComputerName "Hgjyu-79ujk" | 
    Get-Printjob |
        Where-Object {$_.jobstatus -ne "Normal" -and $_.SubmittedTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) } |  # You want -and here.
        Select-Object @{name="Name";expression={$_.printerName}}, 
        @{name="Submitted Time";expression={$_.SubmittedTime}}, 
        jobstatus, PrinterName, 
        @{name="Document Name";expression={$_.documentname}},
        @{n='Time Difference';e={[math]::Truncate(($CurrentTime - $_.SubmittedTime).TotalHours)}} | 
        Sort-Object -Property jobstatus -Descending
```

**EDIT**

As per your comment, if `NodeName` exists as part of `Get-Printer` then you can do this:

```bsh
$CurrentTime = Get-Date

Get-Printer -ComputerName "Hgjyu-79ujk" | Foreach-Object { 
    $Printer = $_
    $Printer | Get-Printjob |
        Where-Object {$_.jobstatus -ne "Normal" -and $_.SubmittedTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) } |  # You want -and here.
        Select-Object @{name="Name";expression={$_.printerName}}, 
        @{name="Submitted Time";expression={$_.SubmittedTime}}, 
        jobstatus, @{name="NodeName";expression={$Printer.NodeName}}, 
        @{name="Document Name";expression={$_.documentname}},
        @{n='Time Difference';e={[math]::Truncate(($CurrentTime - $_.SubmittedTime).TotalHours)}} | 
        Sort-Object -Property jobstatus -Descending
}
```

Please note though that the output you see in PowerShell may be being renamed to have a `NodeName` label. The [MSFT_Printer](https://wutils.com/wmi/root/standardcimv2/msft_printer/) object doesn't normally have that property. You can confirm for sure by running the below to see all the returned object's properties:

```bsh
(Get-Printer)[0] | Format-List *
```

Comment: The example should show you. Note how I haven't formatted the `Get-Date` command at the top. `-Format` sends the output to `[System.String]` instead of `[System.Datetime]`.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked!! Node name is available in Get-Printer -ComputerName "Hgjyu-79ujk". Any idea how to select columns from Get-Printer -ComputerName "Hgjyu-79ujk" and Get-Printer -ComputerName "EdgeQ-6h3gn"  | Get-Printjob.

Comment: Great. I've updated my answer, please note the caveat of the property existing on the output of `Get-Printer`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: I wanted to print when the variable ($PrinterStatus) contains any data in my query using this code but it is not giving accurate results. where I am going wrong any idea?

if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($PrinterStatus))
{
Write-Output "Printers NOT Present" 
}

else {
Write-Output "printers Present"  
}

Comment: Please post a new question of what you have tried with your full code.

Comment: Sure, New question created: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61575752/print-output-whenever-the-variable-returns-data-using-powershell