# Print output whenever the variable returns data using powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, printing

I am trying to print the variable whenever the variable $PrinterStatus is returning any data but the correct data is not coming with If else logic.

```
$CurrentTime = Get-Date
$PrinterStatus= 
Get-Printer -ComputerName "TGHYT-6578UT" | Foreach-Object { 
    $Printer = $_
    $Printer | Get-Printjob | 
        Where-Object {$_.jobstatus -ne "Normal"  -and $_.SubmittedTime -le $CurrentTime.AddHours(-1) } | 
        Select-Object @{name="Printer Name";expression={$_.printerName}}, 
        @{name="Submitted Time";expression={$_.SubmittedTime}}, 
        jobstatus, @{name="Port";expression={$Printer.PortName}}, 
        @{name="Document Name";expression={$_.documentname}},
        @{n='Difference in Hours';e={[math]::Truncate(($CurrentTime - $_.SubmittedTime).TotalHours)}} | 
        Sort-Object -Property jobstatus -Descending
            }

if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($PrinterStatus))
     {
        Write-Output "Printers NOT Present" 
        $output = $PrinterStatus  > "C:\Output.txt"  #Shoud give blank txt file
     }

else {
        Write-Output "printers Present" 
        $output = $PrinterStatus  > "C:\Output.txt" 
     }
```

Comment: But why would you output an array of objects to a text file that way? I would use `Export-Csv`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `$PrinterStatus` will be an array of your custom print job objects, you can check the length of that array.

```bsh
$CurrentTime = Get-Date
$PrinterStatus = @()
$PrinterStatus = Get-Printer -ComputerName "TGHYT-6578UT" | Foreach-Object { 
        Get-Printjob $_ | 
            Where-Object {$_.jobstatus -ne "Normal"  -and $_.SubmittedTime -le $CurrentTime.AddHours(-1) } | 
            Select-Object @{name="Printer Name";expression={$_.printerName}}, @{name="Submitted Time";expression={$_.SubmittedTime}}, @{name="jobstatus";expression={$_.jobstatus}}, @{name="Port";expression={$Printer.PortName}}, @{name="Document Name";expression={$_.documentname}}, @{n='Difference in Hours';e={[math]::Truncate(($CurrentTime - $_.SubmittedTime).TotalHours)}} | 
            Sort-Object -Property jobstatus -Descending
    }

if ($PrinterStatus.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Output "Printers NOT Present"
} else {
    Write-Output "Printers Present"
}
$PrinterStatus  > "C:\Output.txt"
```

I also cleaned up your code a little and fixed the insertion of `jobstatus` in your custom object.